# How I can define last row on each page on multipage table?

Tags: tables, longtable

Is there any way of determination last row of each page in multipage tables. For example if I want add double line on end of each page, or some special content of cells in last row. 
I use the `longtable` package.
Here should be considered, that last rows on pages can be changes, I mean that last row can become the first on the next page, when some additional content will be added to before table.

Comment: For information, this has bee asked on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=17986) too.

Comment: read the documentation of `longtable`. Run `texdoc longtable` there are examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the double `\hline` at the start of the table foot, so

```
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
 \hline\hline
\endfoot
 data&goes&here
...

\end{longtable}
```